# Prefab instantiated as an object with my methods

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an idea that there must be a way to attach a class to a prefab - basically to add my own methods to the code. Then, when I instantiate my prefab in runtime I want it to be an instance of this class.

Now, I can attach a script to a prefab and it's Start and Update works, but my idea is something like this:

```
public class PowerupWidget : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        Debug.Log("PowerupWidget created!!!");
    }
    void SetTitle(string title) {
        // ... set the prefab's title widget text ...
    }
}
```

When I instantiate my prefab, the Start method is called. But the instance is of course the GameObject type.

```
// in my scene script:
// prefab is my PowerupWidget
GameObject p = Instantiate(prefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, this.transform);
// here p is GameObject of course
```

Is there a way how to get to the instance of the PowerupWidget class, or am I completely wrong in my assuptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure in unity :

- Things are divided into entities and component, when entities are gameobject and components are classes(Script) that are attached to this gameobject.

You just need to do this

```
PowerupWidget yourWidget = p.GetComponent<PowerupWidget>();
```